# FOSUserBundle, EventListener registration user

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, registration, event-listener

I'm working on the FOSUserBundle, on EventListener for RegistrationUser.

In this bundle, when I create a user, I use a method updateUser() (in Vendor...Model/UserManagerInterface). This method seems to be subject to an EventListener that triggers at least two actions. Registering the information entered in the database. And sending an email to the user to send them login credentials.

I found the method that sends the mail. By cons, I didn't find the one who makes the recording. I also didn't find where to set the two events.

First for all (and my personal information), I try to find these two points still unknown. If anyone could guide me?

Then, depending on what we decide with our client, I may proceed to a surcharge (which I still don't really know how to do), but I imagine that I would find a little better once my two strangers found

Thanks for your attention and help

Comment: What is the logic? Do you want to listen to the registration event?? Explain better please. FosUser has the events already defined

Comment: They are defined, but I don't find where they are. My problem is that when the registration confirmation email doesn't go away (for one reason or another), account registration isn't done and an error page is displayed in production. It's a logical operation that disturbs our client. We are waiting for a solution to solve the problem of sending mail, but until their IT department finally decides to work, we are studying the question of a temporary solution that no longer blocks registration. Except that I don't find where the events are defined, suddenly, I stuck a little.

Comment: Could you post the error displayed? If the issue is with the sendEmail you probably have a wrong configuration an you are not connecting correctly to your email sever, in the other hand if it is a registration error the email will not be send because that only happens when is trigered onRegistrationSuccess event. Post the error please so I could understand better the problem.

Comment: We know the error and we are working on its resolution. (Error 421 returned by gmail, the customer's IT department is busy providing us with a new smtp service but they are extremely slow). What we want is to change the behavior of the EventListener until the problem is solved. So I'm looking for where the FOSUserBundle EventListener is declared to perform the temporary dressing. (This is the subject of my request, if anyone could tell me how the FOSUserBundle EventListener is declared, not my mail problem :-) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function wich handles the email confirmation on registrationSucces

> FOS\UserBundle\EventListener\EmailConfirmationListener

```
public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var $user \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface */
        $user = $event->getForm()->getData();

        $user->setEnabled(false);
        if (null === $user->getConfirmationToken()) {
            $user->setConfirmationToken($this->tokenGenerator->generateToken());
        }

        $this->mailer->sendConfirmationEmailMessage($user);

        $this->session->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());

        $url = $this->router->generate('fos_user_registration_check_email');
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
```

But I tell you that what you are trying to do is a bad practice. The recommended way is the following.

> Step 1: Select one of the following events to listen(depending on when you want to catch the process)

```
/**
     * The REGISTRATION_SUCCESS event occurs when the registration form is submitted successfully.
     *
     * This event allows you to set the response instead of using the default one.
     *
     * @Event("FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent")
     */
    const REGISTRATION_SUCCESS = 'fos_user.registration.success';

/**
     * The REGISTRATION_COMPLETED event occurs after saving the user in the registration process.
     *
     * This event allows you to access the response which will be sent.
     *
     * @Event("FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent")
     */
    const REGISTRATION_COMPLETED = 'fos_user.registration.completed';
```

> Step 2 Implement the [Event Subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber) with a priority

```
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => [
                'onRegistrationSuccess', 100 //The priority is higher than the FOSuser so it will be called first
            ],
        );
    }
```

> Step 3 Implement your function

```
public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)
    {
       //do your logic here

        $event->stopPropagation();//the Fos User method shall never be called!!
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
```

You never should modify the third party libraries in this case the Event Dispatcher System is made for this to earlier process the event and if its needed stop the propagation and avoid the "re-processing" of the event.

Hope it helps!!!!

Comment: Thank's for your help and suggestions :-)

Comment: @Anna you are welcome, if it worked for you vote up in order to close the topic