# Differenences in event dispatching and handling in Symfony 2.8 and 3.4?

Tags: php, symfony, event-handling

I am working on migrating a `Symfony 2.8` project to `Symfony 3.4`. The project uses `Doctrine 2.6.3` and `FOSUserBundle 2.1.2`.

The project listens to the `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED` to do some extra setup work when a new user account is created and confirmed.

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED => 'onRegistrationConfirmed',
    );
}

public function onRegistrationConfirmed(FilterUserResponseEvent $event) {
    $this->logger->info("onRegistrationConfirmed");        
    $user = $event->getUser();

    // Do some additional setup. While the confirmed user in known here,
    // other setup classes / methods get the current user from tokenStorage 
    ThirdPartySetupCode();
}  


// Some 3rd party class I cannot change
public function ThirdPartySetupCode() {
    $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();

    if (!$token) {
        $user = $token->getUser();
        ...
    }
}
```

It seems that there are some differences in how events are dispatched in handled in `Symfony 2.8` and `Symfony 3.4`:

While the above code runs without any problem in `Symfony 2.8` it fails in `Symfony 3.4` because `$token->getUser()` does not return a valid user object but just the string `anon.`, the anonymous user.

**This is how the events are handled in Symfony 2.8:**

```
dispatch: kernel.request
dispatch: security.authentication.success
dispatch: kernel.controller
dispatch: fos_user.registration.confirm
dispatch: fos_user.registration.confirmed
dispatch: fos_user.security.implicit_login
onRegistrationConfirmed
```

It is surprising, that the `onRegistrationConfirmed` log output appear **directly after** `fos_user.registration.confirmed`. Shouldn't the handler be executed directly after the event was fired?

Instead the `fos_user.security.implicit_login` event is dispatched (and handled?) first, and only then `onRegistrationConfirmed` handler?

**Why is this?** However, while I do not understand this behavior it leads to the desired result: Since the handler (and with it the 3rd party code) runs after the login is complete, the token returns the correct user.

**This is how the events are handled in Symfony 3.4:**

```
dispatch: kernel.request
dispatch: security.authentication.success
dispatch: kernel.controller
dispatch: kernel.controller_arguments
dispatch: fos_user.registration.confirm 
dispatch: fos_user.registration.confirmed
onRegistrationConfirmed
dispatch: fos_user.security.implicit_login
```

Here the `onRegistrationConfirmed` handler is executed directly after the `fos_user.registration.confirmed` event.

While I understand this behavior it leads to the wrong result: The handler (and with it the 3rd party code) runs BEVOR the login in complete and thus the token does not return a valid user.

**How to address this problem?** Since I cannot change the 3rd party code I would have to delay the handling of `fos_user.registration.confirmed` somehow, so that the login in completed first. Can this be done?

**Is this difference in event dispatching and handling an intended change between `Symfony 2.8` and `Symfony 3.4`? I did not find any information on this.**

Comment: see, i was kind in the right direction, can you check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50352121/fosuserbundle-eventlistener-registration-user ?